# Where can I find a detailed derivation of the form of two-body operators in the second quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, resource-recommendations, second-quantization

I've been looking around online for a couple hours now and I can't find a very informative derivation of the form for two body operators in the second quantization.

Is there a resource online (lecture notes or a video lecture?) that goes through this in detail? Or, failing that, is there a textbook you would recommend to me? Or would you like to write me a step by step explanation?

In particular, I'm going to try to model electrons on a lattice and while I think that I could write down the coulomb terms in the hamiltonian in terms of some constant times a product of creation and annihilation operators I don't understand what I would be writing down very well - it would be more of an exercise of copying and pasting than anything else.

Comment: I also could never find this so I wrote my own. I'll send it to you if you email me (see my profile page and follow the link to my research group's member list).

Comment: In textbooks - Landau&Livshitz, Fetter&Walecka, AGD

Comment: In basically all many-body books, no? For example, Negele & Orland.

Answer (score 0):

There is a derivation in Fetter and Walecka, as well as another treatment in Sakurai. I haven't looked at these in a while and they may or may not provide the mental satisfaction you are looking for, but it is worth looking at these two treatments at any rate.

Comment: Thanks! I'm slowly chipping away at the mountain of things I don't understand and this helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean e-e Coulomb interactions, Quantum Theory of Solids by C. Kittel Chapter 5 on second quantization is pretty comprehensive. Quantum liquids by David Pines also has some similar discussions on this in Chapter 5. Unless I misunderstood what you are trying to understand, I think lots of condensed matter field theory books would have it.

Comment: Didn't realize this is a very old post... Somehow it's at the top of my question page..

Answer (score 0):

I particularly like the treatment in the first chapter of F. Schwabl's *Advanced Quantum Mechanics*.